# Using Contact Form 7 in Elementor but can't align textbox properly

Tags: css, wordpress, textbox, contact-form-7, elementor

I tried to align my textbox in contact form 7 and something weird happened when I styled the width on each text box.
The "Text1"&"Text2" are using the same styled css as "Text3"&"Text4".

They are all following  and I set the width of contact0 to 50%. But why are these two form showing differently?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HP2h8.png
[image]
Contact Form 7

```
<div>
    <form id="contact0">
[email* eml  placeholder "Text1"]
[text phn  placeholder "Text2"]
    </form>
</div>
<div>
    <form id="contact0">
[email* eml  placeholder "Text3"]
[text phn  placeholder "Text4"]
    </form>
</div><div>
    <form id="contact1">
[email* eml  placeholder "Text5"]
[text phn  placeholder "Text6"]
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS

```
CSS
#contact0{
    width: 48%;
    float: left;
}
#contact1{
    width: 48%;
    float: right;
}
```

Thank you so much for answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend to style elements in your form not creating three forms, like you did.

For Example:

**Contact Form 7**

```
 <div class="contact-form-style">
 <p class="style1">[text* text placeholder "Name*"]</p>
 <p class="style2">[email* email placeholder "Email*"]</p>
 <p class="style2">[textarea* textarea placeholder "Textt*"]</p>
 [submit "Submit"]
 </div>
```

Then try to style it this way:

**style.css**

```
 .contact-form-style {
 /* your CSS */
 }
 .style1 {
 /* your CSS */
 }
.style2 {
 /* your CSS */
 }
```